# Angular + Overrides Chrome DevTools

Tags: angular, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, chrome-debugging

I am trying to use the Chrome DevTools feature Overrides with an Angular project, but I'm not being able to do it.
I have sourcemap configured, so I can make use of debugger to setup breakpoints, but when I modify de file, the browser is not making use of the modified file through the sourcemap.
It seems the browser is using the compiled js file.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overrides/

I tried with different angular.json build configurations in a new angular project just created.
But nothing worked.
What I expect is that the browser makes use of the modified component, service, etc. so I can try things directly in the browser avoiding compile time.

Thanks in advance.